# How to prove : $6\mathbb Z /24\mathbb Z $ is an ideal in $\mathbb Z /24\mathbb Z $ , what are elements of $6\mathbb Z /24\mathbb Z $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Prove : $6\mathbb Z/24\mathbb Z$ is an ideal in $\mathbb Z/24\mathbb Z$. Is this ideal maximal? Is $\mathbb Z $ /24$\mathbb Z $ an integral domain?

I don't know what are elements of $6\mathbb Z/24\mathbb Z$, that's why I don't know how to start with this proof. What I know:
$\mathbb Z/24\mathbb Z$ contains the 24 residue classes. So: $\mathbb Z /24\mathbb Z =\{0,1,...,23\}$.

Comment: Hint: $6\Bbb{Z}$ is all integer multiples of $6$, now you want to mod them out by $24$. So ask yourself what relation should $a$ and $b$ have so that $6a \equiv 6b \pmod{24}$? See if this helps in determining the **distinct** equivalence classes (in the sense can you say $a \equiv b \pmod{??}$. This will give you an idea of what the set $6\Bbb{Z}/24\Bbb{Z}$ will look like.

Comment: so I suppose, it is reduced to $ a≡b (mod4) $, does that mean that elements of set 6 $\mathbb Z/24$$\mathbb Z$ are {0,1,2,3}

Comment: Yes now we can say that $6\Bbb{Z}/24\Bbb{Z}=\{[0]_{24}, [1]_{24}, [2]_{24}, [3]_{24},\}$.

Comment: I get it, thank you!

Comment: Another question,  what do I take for "general" element of this set, for checking the definition of an ideal?

Comment: To determine whether $6\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z$ is a maximal ideal  in  $\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z$, you can compute the quotient and use the *3rd isomorphism theorem*.

Comment: @petrms So we can also say that $6\Bbb{Z}/24\Bbb{Z}=\{[6a]_{24} \, | \, a \in \Bbb{Z}\}$. So now you know what a typical element looks like.